# How to find defining plugins for the eclipse File menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In eclipse its possible to position the mouse cursor on an item and press Alt+Shift+F1 to open the PluginSpy and get info on the source files for the focused item.

But how do I inspect (find all org.eclipse.ui.menus contributions for a menu) eg. the menu contributions that make up the File menu in eclipse?

Eg. is it possible to find the plugin that add the "Recent Files list" in the bottom of the file menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt+Shift+F2 will open the "Plugin Menu Spy", you can use that to get information on menus.

Using this I found out that the active contribution item identifier for the list in question is "reopenEditors". Googling for that led me to [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/actions/ContributionItemFactory.html). This probably answers your question :).

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the link. I have tried to put that in the  fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) method in the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor. But it only works when I use the eclipse default Open File... action. I need to make it work with my own files types that are basically a project in the navigator.

Comment: @Tul - This action maintains the list of all recently opened editors, so if your files can be opened in an editor, they should be listed.

Comment: ContributionItemFactory.REOPEN_EDITORS works for me. However, when my RCP app start, it displays empty list. How to make it to be saved in the preferences?

Answer (score 1):

The editor history items are contributed by org.eclipse.ui.internal.ReopenEditorMenu. Its not only maintains the list of the files opened by "Open File...", but all the editors opened by IWorkbenchPage.openEditor() methods.

Comment: Thats the tricky part. The RCP app I am working on does not associate an editor with the opened file. Actually it associates it with a view. I have tried :     menu.add(ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHOW_IN.create(window));
. But then I just be a grayed item saying "No applicable view".

Comment: Long story but that is how its is now and not likely to be changed in the future. I have created my own Open File Handler is it possible to override/defined a method that add the opened file to some "recent files" stack?

Comment: @Tul - You are getting this message because you haven't specified the view as a valid showInPart. You need to add a perspectiveExtensions extension, then declare the view as a showInPart. It's all better explained here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm